# Difference between limit and limit point

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My question is that ,what is the diffrence between limit and limit point?

Comment: say the objects involved

Comment: Be careful with the definitions here, they're not always used in exactly the same way, for instance, some authors consider accumulation point to be a synonym for limit point, but others make a distinction between to two terms. So what are your definitions for these things (e.g. do you have a specific source whose definitions you are using or if not, how would you define those two terms?)